# Xcode+SVN: Files in another directory (outside project folder)

Tags: xcode, svn

I have two related projects and some common/shared code in a folder layout like this:

/path/to/ProjectA/
(inside is ProjectA.xcodeproj + all of its source files)

/path/to/ProjectB/
(inside is ProjectB.xcodeproj + all of its source files)

/path/to/Common/
(inside are 5 headers shared by both ProjectA and ProjectB)

Everything's fine except that Xcode is not showing changes made to the shared files in the Groups & Files pane of either project.

Both projects have been imported to SVN separately.  And the shared folder was imported to SVN separately.

How do I -- without changing the folder layout -- set this up so that if I'm in either one of the 2 projects and I make a change to a shared file, Xcode will recognize that a change has been made to that file and allow me to check in the changes?

Comment: I am also struggling with this issue. Have you ever found a solution to this yet?